How can I add a vertical scrollbar to HTMLView (react-native-htmlview)?
I'm trying to show a text that contain HTML tags in HTMLView, but when the text have multiples lines, I can scroll vertically on mobile, any help will be appreciated.
The part of code that uses HTMLView:
 <ScrollView
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.tafseerContent}
      >
        <HTMLView
          value={tafseerText}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          stylesheet={{
            p: {
              color: textColor,
              fontFamily: 'Amiri_400Regular',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            },
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>`


Then i used it in my component like this:
...
  {tafseerData ? (
        <ThemedView
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            height: '100%',
          }}
        >
          {renderTafseerContent(tafseerData)}
        </ThemedView>
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={tintColor} />
      )}
    </ThemedView>
...


